# Thoughts on a word-choice tag?

Tags: discussion

We have a few questions about the selection of particular words in a phrase or poem. Examples:

[Language in A View from the Bridge](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/language-in-a-view-from-the-bridge)

[What is the rhetorical purpose of the description of Miss Emily?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3595/what-is-the-rhetorical-purpose-of-the-description-of-miss-emily)

Since we do tag sub-topics within literature with things like "character-analysis", I'm thinking it might be useful and appropriate to have a tag for questions like these.

Apparently the literate term for this is "lexis" but I reckon it best if we just stick with the much more user friendly "word-choice".

Thoughts? Happy to do the tagging myself if it's agreed as a good idea.

Comment: Apropos of nothing, congrats on 4k rep! It's great to have more people with Trusted User powers :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks. I've nearly got as much rep here in a year as it's taken me 8 years to accrue on SO. Now I just need to find some way to abuse my new privileges!

Comment: I've gone ahead and created a tag called [tag:wording-choice] to add it to these questions. I'll leave the tag wiki to you :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks, have edited the wiki  and added a few more questions to the tag.

Answer (score 7):

In principle, yes, there should be a tag for this as there could be many useful questions in this regard.

However, I'm not convinced that [word-choice](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) is a good name for it.  It implies the choice of a single word, not the phraseology of a passage.  Maybe something like [turn-of-phrase](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-of-phrase), which I admit can probably be improved upon.

Alternatively, go with [lexis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexis) to be accurate, then, if other ways of stating it come up, synonymise the tags to point at the [lexis](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexis) master.

Comment: How about `wording-choice`? "Wording" doesn't necessarily suggest just a single word.

Comment: @rand-althor maybe choice-of-words ? We just need to pick one and I'll get tagging

Comment: I vote for `wording-choice.` That covers individual words and entire turns of phrase. "Lexis" to me means the law library, and some people are going to think it's a typo for the automotive brand.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend replacing [meaning](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) with this new tag. Meaning is an incredibly vague tag, so vague that it's used inconsistently and doesn't really have any real purpose. Word choice or whatever you choose to go with seems like a more specific alternative.

I also recommend starting with a few questions, and seeing if the tag catches on first.